# How to batch update Box enterpise users

Tags: box-api

I have successfully pulled back a list of enterprise users using the Box API:
http://developers.box.com/docs/

I now want to batch update a group of users, setting the group to Inactive.

In the API, I see that you can update a single user like this: `PUT /users/{id}`

I believe I can just loop through a list of users from a .csv file and individually set each of them to "inactive" via the method above. The problem is that I don't know the ID of each user to include in the .csv file. If I export the users via the Box Admin Console's "Bulk Edit" feature, I get a .csv file of the users, but it only contains the following columns: Name, Email, Groups, and Storage.

So, my first thought is that there may be some way to update the user through the API using the email address.
As in, first search for the user via the email address, then get the ID from the results, and finally use the returned ID to update the user account. Is this possible or can you suggest another way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

George, the [Get All Users in an Enterprise](http://developers.box.com/docs/#users-get-all-the-users-in-an-enterprise) feature allows you to filter users by login (email).  The request would follow this format:

`GET /users?filter_term=USERNAME`

or, if necessary,

`GET /users?filter_term=USERNAME%40DOMAIN.COM`

You can then use the ID of that user to persist the updates as you've suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can 'Get All Users in an Enterprise.' This will give you all of the users in the account, including their email addresses and user ids. Once you have that, you can update them all individually.

http://developers.box.com/docs/#users